# .NET and Windows Cultures different from standards

Tags: c#, .net, momentjs, culture

If I run the following C# code

```
var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("af");       
Console.WriteLine(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

I get the output of yyyy-MM-dd.

However if I use momentjs on the client and run the following code

```
var localeData = moment.localeData('af');
console.log(localeData._config.longDateFormat.L);
```

I get output of DD/MM/YYYY.

Why are they different? Research indicates the momentjs one is probably right. This is a problem if I enter a date in the client and then try and parse it on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("af");
```

Which equates to

```
af-ZA   Afrikaans - South Africa    0x0436  AFK
```

---

[Date and time notation in South Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_South_Africa)

> South Africa signed up to use ISO 8601 for date and time
>   representation through national standard ARP 010:1989 in 1998. The
>   most recent South African Bureau of Standards standard SANS 8601:2009
>   "... is the identical implementation of ISO 8601:2004, and is adopted
>   with the permission of the International Organization for
>   Standardization" and was reviewed in 2016.

**Date Remark**

> Even so, the old date format is still commonly used in the format
>   "dd/mm/yyyy", with the "day month year" order being more common with
>   non-numeric month designations.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

```
YYYY-MM-DD  or  YYYYMMDD
```

---

[.NET Framework Cultures with Date and Time String Formats](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx)

```
English Name                Abbreviation    ShortDate Format    
Afrikaans (South Africa)    af-ZA           yyyy/MM/dd
```

---

**In all honesty** : `momentjs` seems wrong

Comment: Thanks. I tend to agree with you MomentJs sounds wrong, it sounds like it is going with the 'commonly used' format as opposed to the 'technically correct' format.

Comment: @Craig no worries :)